# Too many levels of symbol links and as result console programs cannot be executed

Tags: linux, filesystems

I've got a problem. Something bad happened with my filesystem.
Git denies to push files, but I could do with it init, commit and add remote.

[image]

GNU g++ compiler doesn't compile.

[image]

QtCreator can compile programs, but I can't do it manually.

I really wouldn't like to reinstall the whole system, but I need git and make utilities.
I can't localise this problem.

Comment: Can you run `ls -l` In your Dropbox/rhythmbox_pack_copy/ folder?

Comment: And the parent 'Dropbox' folder.

Comment: yes, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18776391/03%3A54%3A5129092013_001.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18776391/03%3A56%3A0229092013_001.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `PATH` is messed up. As par with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027740/makefile-and-symbolic-links/. To quote:

> "I believe it is saying there are too many levels of symbolic links
>   while trying to locate the... command itself [within the path]."

For an easy way out, you could reinstall. However, this might not be an option.

To localise the issue try to look through your path for symbolic links. Here is a small bash script to do that. Just make a file, copy this in:

```
for path in ${PATH//:/ }; do
    echo "Printing links for: $path"
    readlink "$path"
    echo "Done."
done
```

Then run the file with `bash [FILENAME]` where filename is the name of the file you just created.

Comment: yes, it was messed with old unused links I cleaned unnecessary up and rebooted